# Laravel Passport- Protect routes for different user types

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I am using `passport` in `laravel` for authenticating my users in APIs. I am able to authenticate different types of users from different tables and generating different token for them but the routes are not protected. For example. 
A user can access the routes like this

```
Route::group(['middleware'  =>  'auth:api'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix'  =>  'v1'], function () {
        Route::get('get-seller-list','API\v1\SellersController@index');
    });
});
```

and a seller can access the routes like

```
Route::group(['middleware'  =>  'auth:sellers'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix'  =>  'v1'], function () {
    Route::get('get-seller-detail','API\v1\TestController@getDetails');
    });
});
```

but this `middleware` check doesn't seem to be working as I can access all the routes for sellers even if I have passed the token generated for api in Bearer header.

My config/auth.php looks like

```
'guards' => [
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'seller' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'sellers',
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Hi, i have same problem. how can resolve problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `auth:api` middleware will handle the passport token authentication and the `sellers` middleware will check if users are sellers. I think you are getting mixed up with the way the middleware is set up.

This sort of depends on how you have your user types set up but in your `sellers` middleware you can check for User types / roles:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class Sellers
{
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->user()->is_seller) {
            return $next($request);
        }

         return response()->view('errors.401', [], 401);
    }
}
```

Then you can set your route up to use both `auth:api` and `sellers` middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware'  =>  ['auth:api', 'sellers']], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix'  =>  'v1'], function () {
    Route::get('get-seller-detail','API\v1\TestController@getDetails');
    });
});
```

So now if a normal user tries to access the `get-seller-detail` route it will return a 401 unauthorized error and if a seller tries to access this route it will proceed to the code for that route as normal.